# Does Angular uses built-in hooks/events (e.g. when a directive is created)?

Tags: angularjs

I know that Angular supports custom events via `$emit`/`$broadcast`, but does Angular uses hooks/events internally? E.g. can I use a callback every time some Angular built-in task is handled like creating a directive. (So you could log every newly created directive or something like that.)

Comment: Generally speaking - Events, no. Hooks, yes. Angular walks the DOM tree and provides hooks to compile and link your directives. There are also hooks to run code after certain stages of angular compilation (before compile, after compile, before link, after link, after render, etc)

Comment: You refer to the hooks for the directive itself, or? I would like to listen to global hooks (like in the logging example).